# Как получить переменную в объекте

Tags: javascript

Нужно создать объект описывающий прямоугольник двумя точками(верхний левый и правый нижний угол). Далее нужно написать функцию, которая принимает обьект прямоугольник и возражает его сторону , далее нужно написать функцию которая принимает обьект прямоугольник и на сколько изменить его ширину

```js
let rectangle = {
    x1: 0,
    y1: 10,
    x2: 10,
    y2: 2,
};

rectangle.returnWeight = function(){ 
      let weight =  Math.abs(this.x2) - Math.abs(this.x1);
      alert(`Ширина прямоугольника равна ${weight}`);
      return weight;
};
//Метод для определения ширины 
rectangle.changeWeight = function(parametr){
       let newWeight =  (Math.abs(this.x2) - Math.abs(this.x1)) + parametr;
       alert(`Ширина прямоугольника была = ${weight} , а стала = ${newWeight}`);
       return newWeight;
};
```

Как написать метод который изменяет ширину . У меня возникла проблема , новый метод changeWeight не видит переменную из метода weight. Конечно можно сделать метод таким образом что я просто как в методе returnWeight измеряю ширину текущего прямоугольника , а затем просто добавляю параметр к этой ширине. Но мне интересно как это можно сделать ещё. Можно ли получить доступ к этой переменной weight или может стоит инициализировать эту переменную в самом объекте , а в методе просто её взять

Я решил сделать так

```js
rectangle.changeWeight = function(parametr){
       this.x2 += parametr;
       let newWeight =  Math.abs(this.x2) - Math.abs(this.x1);
       alert(`Новая ширина прямоугольника ${newWeight}`);
       return newWeight;
};
```

Comment: Я возражаю это выражение:  `Math.abs(this.x2)`

Comment: Не совсем понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

объедините все в один объект - удобно читать и есть общая область видимости:

```
const rect = {
  _x: [],
  _y: [],

  getWidth: function () {
    return this._x[1] - this._x[0]
  },

  setCoord: function (coordinate) {
    const {x,y} = coordinate;
    this._x = x.sort()
    this._y = y.sort()
  },

  setWidth: function (width) {
    this._x[1] = this._x[0] + Math.abs(width);
  }
}
```

Добавить метод установки координат показалось логичным, но вы можете изменить пример под свой вариант использования. Проверим работоспособность:

```
rect.setCoord({x: [5,2], y: [7,15]});
console.log(rect.getWidth()); //3
rect.setWidth(5);
console.log(rect.getWidth()); //5

rect.setCoord({x: [-10, 3], y: [2,12]});
console.log(rect.getWidth()); //13
rect.setWidth(8);
console.log(rect.getWidth()); //8

rect.setCoord({x: [5, 3], y: [-2,12]});
console.log(rect.getWidth()); //2
rect.setWidth(4);
console.log(rect.getWidth()); //4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(`Ширина прямоугольника была = ${this.returnWeight()} , а стала = ${newWeight}`);
```

Но лучше в методах ничего не алертить. Сделай так чтоб методы просто возвращали значения

```
rectangle.returnWeight = function(){  
      return Math.abs(this.x2) - Math.abs(this.x1);
};

//Метод для определения ширины 
rectangle.changeWeight = function(parametr){
       return (Math.abs(this.x2) - Math.abs(this.x1)) + parametr;
};

alert(`Ширина прямоугольника была = ${rectangle.returnWeight()} , а стала = ${rectangle.changeWeight()}`);
```

Comment: Спасибо,  а вот если к примеру нам нужно будет сделать что то с прямоугольником в новом методе , но что бы это сделать нужно использовать  к примеру значение weight и changeWeight  , можно ли тогда к примеру инициализировать эти переменные в самом объекте , а в методе просто использовать иначе в том методе где нам нужно использовать их значение нам придётся к примеру писать не weight , а  Math.abs(this.x2) - Math.abs(this.x1);

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос.
Ты можешь определить weight как поле, чтоб каждый раз не вычислять значение функции weight.
И можешь создать сколько угодно функций changeWeight(с разным названием), которые будут выполнять разные действия над объектом и в том числе его полем weight